# How to create two subframes of equal size?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes:

df1

```
col1  col2  col3
c     3     0
a     3     0
a     4     0
c     1     0
v     3     1
d     3     1
e     2     0
f     2     0
```

df2

```
col1  col2  col3
a     3     0
a     4     0
c     1     0
v     3     0
d     3     0
e     2     0
a     1     0
e     8     0
e     9     0
f     2     1
i     1     0
```

I need to create two sub-dataframes `df1_sub` and `df2_sub`, so that:

- `df1_sub` and `df2_sub` have the same number of rows, equal to 5.

  - the number of rows before `col3==1` is equal to 3 and the number of rows after `col3==1` is equal to 1 (thus, totally 5 rows). Let's assume that this rule is always implementable.

The expected output:

df1_sub

```
col1  col2  col3
a     3     0
a     4     0
c     1     0
v     3     1
d     3     1
```

df2_sub

```
col1  col2  col3
a     1     0
e     8     0
e     9     0
f     2     1
i     1     0
```

Comment: So... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @mozway: I've just added the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @Lecdi: I've tried `df1.head(5)`, but it does not guarantee that the rows of `col3` equal to 1 are included. I also tried to detect the index of `col3==1` and then count 3 rows backward and 1 row forward. But it neither returns me the fixed number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `shift` and `cummax` to get the start and subsequent values and `head` to limit the total length:

```
def sub(df, before=3, after=1):
    mask = df['col3'].eq(1).shift(-before, fill_value=True).cummax()
    return df[mask].head(before+after+1)
```

Example:

```
sub(df1)
  col1  col2  col3
1    a     3     0
2    a     4     0
3    c     1     0
4    v     3     1
5    d     3     1

sub(df2)
   col1  col2  col3
6     a     1     0
7     e     8     0
8     e     9     0
9     f     2     1
10    i     1     0
```

Comment: What about `df.iloc[(i:=df.col3.eq(1).idxmax())-3:i+2]`